# Percentages from individual rows don't balance with total row percentage

Tags: excel, math, sum, percentage

Maybe someone could help explain to me why such a situation doesn't work out.
So let say for example, we have two sets of data, DATA A (People) and DATA B (Vehicles, which breaks down into Trucks and Cars). Each row are departments, where People have access to vehicles of that same department.

So we look at the ratio of Trucks to Cars (we find out % of Trucks) and then based on that ratio, we make a very silly estimate of how many people we assume will have Trucks, contained to their department.

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
|        | DATA A |          DATA B          |               |       |
|        | People | Trucks   Cars    Truck%  | Ratio Applied |       |
+        +--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
| DEPT A | 50     | 20       100      20.00% | 10            |       |
| DEPT B | 30     | 30       100      30.00% | 9             |       |
| DEPT C | 10     | 40       100      40.00% | 4             |       |
| DEPT D | 100    | 20       100      20.00% | 20            |       |
| DEPT E | 80     | 25       100      25.00% | 20            | 63.00 |
+        +--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
|        | 270    | 135      500    | 27.00% | 72.90         |       |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
```

Explaining the above, let's look at Data B first. There is a ratio of 20:100 Trucks to Cars (20%) for Department A, then 30:100 for Department B and so on. So that gives us the Truck% for each Department. We then use that percentage on each row of People. So 20% of 50 people is 10 (for Department A), 30% of 30 people all from Department B is 9 and so on. After that, we add them all together as they are and it equals 63 people using Trucks.

HOWEVER, when we start to look at the TOTAL Trucks to Cars, it is 27%. We then apply that 27% to the TOTAL amount of people, 27% x 270 = 72.90. This is more than the 63 we came to earlier. Why is this not balancing to the same figure?

It'll probably be a stupidly easy answer, but I just wanted to get some external confirmation that this is all wrong.

Comment: If there are 20 trucks and 100 cars, the percent of trucks is 100*(20/(20+100))

Comment: but also, your prediction is not weighted. The 20 to 100 in department D matters more than what is going on in department C, and just summing cars and trucks does not respect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how the data should look and how it should match up.
[image: spreadsheet]

There are 2 issues in your calculations that led to the mismatch. I am copying formulas based on my sheet, but these can be adapted to yours.

First, the percent should be `=100*C4/(C4+D4)`, not the ratio you calculated.

Second, the totaling of percents needs to be weighted based on the number of people. Thus it should be `=(B4/B9)*E4+(B5/B9)*E5+(B6/B9)*E6+(B7/B9)*E7+(B8/B9)*E8`. When that is multiplied by the total number of people (and divided by 100), it does indeed yield the same thing as when you sum the number of cars by department with `=sum(F4:F8)`